# Update Laravel main app directory

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Is there an easy way to incorporate changes to the main Laravel app, when there are framework updates, other than manually incorporating the changes described in the documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade)?

I'm thinking some kind of composer command that patches the main app and not only the vendor dir. Does such a thing exist?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was also in search of something like that

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, *Shift* is exactly what you're looking for, although it's still in its alpha. You can contact its creator if you want to help him test the tool.

Reference: http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2015/11/laravel-automated-upgrade-tool-shift/